# Can I have two conditions which must both be met in an updateOrInsert call?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

From reading the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#updates) I know that `updateOrInsert` takes two arguments, the first of which is an array of conditions. This array is compared one by one, not all at once - i.e., given the array `['name' => 'John', 'email' => 'contact@example.com']` it will first check for a row(s) with `name == 'John'` and then, iff it doesn't find one, it looks for a row(s) with `email == 'contact@example.com'`.

I want to have two conditions which must both be met - i.e. it will only update a row(s) if it has `name == 'John'`**`AND`**`email == 'contact@example.com'`.

Is there a nice way to do this with the updateOrInsert function, or do I need to use an if statement and an extra call to check both conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that like that, that is already  in documentation

```
DB::table('users')
    ->updateOrInsert(
        ['email' => 'john@example.com', 'name' => 'John'],
        ['votes' => '2']
    );
```

It will check if `email == 'john@example.com'` and `name == 'john'`, then it will update `votes=2`.

Answer (score 1):

`updateOrInsert` should behave just as you would want it to behave. The first argument it takes is an and-connected array of conditions. The second parameter is an array to merge the conditions with and update any matched record with.

```php
    /**
     * Insert or update a record matching the attributes, and fill it with values.
     *
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @param  array  $values
     * @return bool
     */
    public function updateOrInsert(array $attributes, array $values = [])
    {
        if (! $this->where($attributes)->exists()) {
            return $this->insert(array_merge($attributes, $values));
        }
        if (empty($values)) {
            return true;
        }
        return (bool) $this->take(1)->update($values);
    }
```

Code from https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/bc31b3b22c44fcc797ad4e5a6f95f5bccdd63acc/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L2699